# expand/collapse all not working with mat-accordion

Tags: angular-material

Based on material 2 demo-app i have created a demo for expand-all/collapse-all funcationality for matAccordian.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmitne?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html

expandall button isn't working as it unable to find accordion.openAll() function. I have seen openAll() is defined in the CdkAccordion class which is being inherited by MatAccordion, but somehow it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is because such functionality has only been released in `6.0.0-beta.0` and your Stackblitz is still on `5.2.1`. (see [this commit](https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/3aceb7361cc34ad987f7b1ca39339d3203248341) for more info).

Here's the [changelog (`v6.0.0-beta.0`)](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#6.0.0-beta-0) for more info.

---

<sub>P.s. did you know you can install specific versions of a dependency on Stackblitz?</sub>

[Updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/working-multi-expand-so)